# Auto mail sender in IOS phonegap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, cordova

How can we send mail or sms automated from ios phone gap application for every one minute with out user interference? Is it possible ?

Give me some good articles OR to achieve my requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible from device end. You can write services on your server ends. Whenever require, you will need to invoke the service. The backend server should have SMTP configured or SMS gateway integration for email and SMS stuff.

Comment: How can we write services on server ends? Can you please suggest some good articles for the same ?

Comment: Its a much broad question. You need to decide backend technology first and then you can start looking for same.

Answer (score 0):

No this is not possible and would be a breach of privacy. Think about it, you will send a SMS to a paid service without the user knowing it.

You could use your own own email/sms provider and solve it this way.

Comment: Thanks for replay. Sms is a paid service and Is it possible for auto mail send

Comment: Like I said in my answer NO it is not possible, neither for SMS nor mail.\